# RoboHelp 2019 and 2 Users

Tags: installation, multiple-users, robohelp

How do we setup RH Version 2019 Classic for 2 users to create and maintain multiple Help projects?  We don't need both users to be in the same Help project at the same time, but we do need for each of them to make changes to the various projects as needed.

We have installed RH 2019 Classic on each desktop and both have access to SharePoint.  One of the users has been creating and maintaining these files for years.  We are now adding a 2nd writer to the team.